# Inductors on square forms

Tags: inductor

Would an inductor wound on a form with a square cross section have similar characteristics to one wrapped on a circular one of similar size?

Comment: You will not gain anything from doing it, rather the opposite. DC resistance will go up due to longer length of turn, more core losses due to larger volume yet same peak current capability due to same cross sectional area at the narrowest point.

Comment: Sometimes you have to wind an inductor on a square form to maximize the aperture.

Answer (score 3):

For a given core area, it will have a longer periphery ==> slightly higher (factor of 4/pi) DC resistance.

Comment: I vaguely remember also that the self-capacitance will be greater towards the corners, so the apparent total parasitic capacitance will be larger. But don't quote me on that.

Comment: Mechanical (and electrical ?) stress would be also higher on the corners?